# output from glm in R does not include variable name

Tags: r, glm

I am writing an R script that tests the association of 150,000 genetic markers with a continuous variable using glm.nb

I wrote the following to do this:

```
fhandle<-file("ichip_nb_model.csv","a")
for (i in seq(7, ncol(ICHPdt), 1)) {
     glmmod<-glm.nb(OverllTot0 ~ EurAdmix + Sex + DisDurMonths + BMI + Group + SmokingStatus + eval(parse(text = paste("ICHPdt$", colnames(ICHPdt)[i], sep=""))), data=covfiledt)
     writeLines(capture.output(coef(summary(glmmod))), con=fhandle)
     writeLines(colnames(ICHPdt)[i], con=fhandle)
 }
```

However, this leads to a problem. The output written in the first writeLines statement does not contain the column name, it includes the entire `eval` expression instead (see the Current Output section, below). But I do not want the eval expression, I want what that *evaluates to* because the column header is the name of the genetic marker being tested.

So, as a stop-gap, I added the second writeLines statment, but I would prefer to find a solution that simply would result in the name of the variant being displayed. 
The output that the script produces is in the following format:

Current Output

```
    Estimate      Std. Error    z value
        (Intercept)                                                         -0.960341597 0.898711395 -1.0685762
        EurAdmix                                                             2.055048065 1.132148532  1.8151753
        Sex                                                                  0.783616302 0.369298081  2.1219073
        DisDurMonths                                                        -0.013458018 0.002786449 -4.8298098
        BMI                                                                 -0.008077163 0.012892372 -0.6265071
        Group                                                               -0.059876340 0.288834615 -0.2073032
        SmokingStatus                                                       -0.089029296 0.185598042 -0.4796888
        eval(parse(text = paste("ICHPdt$", colnames(ICHPdt)[i], sep = ""))) -0.108334664 0.169464866 -0.6392751
                                                                                Pr(>|z|)
        (Intercept)                                                         2.852607e-01
        EurAdmix                                                            6.949697e-02
        Sex                                                                 3.384552e-02
        DisDurMonths                                                        1.366635e-06
        BMI                                                                 5.309824e-01
        Group                                                               8.357731e-01
        SmokingStatus                                                   

6.314487e-01
    eval(parse(text = paste("ICHPdt$", colnames(ICHPdt)[i], sep = ""))) 5.226440e-01
```

Desired output:

```
        Estimate      Std. Error    z value
            (Intercept)                                                         -0.960341597 0.898711395 -1.0685762
            EurAdmix                                                             2.055048065 1.132148532  1.8151753
            Sex                                                                  0.783616302 0.369298081  2.1219073
            DisDurMonths                                                        -0.013458018 0.002786449 -4.8298098
            BMI                                                                 -0.008077163 0.012892372 -0.6265071
            Group                                                               -0.059876340 0.288834615 -0.2073032
            SmokingStatus                                                       -0.089029296 0.185598042 -0.4796888
            ICHPdt$rs728931
-0.108334664 0.169464866 -0.6392751


        Pr(>|z|)
                (Intercept)                                                         2.852607e-01
                EurAdmix                                                            6.949697e-02
                Sex                                                                 3.384552e-02
                DisDurMonths                                                        1.366635e-06
                BMI                                                                 5.309824e-01
                Group                                                               8.357731e-01
                SmokingStatus                                                       6.314487e-01
                ICHPdt$rs728931
5.226440e-01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result from summary.glm(fit)$coefficients is what you want and it would be simple matter to change the name of the 8th rowname to the desired character value. Perhaps using `write.table` would save some of the clunkiness that `capture.output` imposes (unless, of course, you really do want the wrap-around with the 'Pr(>|t|)' name values:

```
fhandle<-file("ichip_nb_model.csv","a")
for (i in seq(7, ncol(ICHPdt), 1)) {
     glmmod<-glm.nb(OverllTot0 ~ EurAdmix + Sex + DisDurMonths + BMI + Group + SmokingStatus + eval(parse(text = paste("ICHPdt$", colnames(ICHPdt)[i], sep=""))), data=covfiledt)
     summ <- coef(summary(glmmod)))
     rownames(summ)[8] <- paste0("ICHPdt$", colnames(ICHPdt)[i])
     write.table( round(summ, 4) file=fhandle)
 }
```

Comment: Really? You left `eval(parse())` in there? I'm surprised.

Comment: I won't judge you. ;) Using write.table already makes it way better.

Comment: I was rather stunned that it worked. I didn't realize you could do that.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost never necessary to use `eval(parse())`. In this case it would be easier to build the formula as a string and then send that to the call. I'm assuming you're using the `glm.nb()` function from the `MASS` package. Here's a sample of dynamically building the formula

```
library(MASS)

other <- data.frame(matrix(runif(nrow(quine)*3), nrow=nrow(quine)))    

lapply(names(other), function(x) {
    ff<-as.formula(paste0("Days ~ Sex/(Age + Eth*Lrn) + other$", x))
    glm.nb(ff, data = quine)
})
```

Although really, grabbing some values from a different data set isn't usualyl a great idea. Have `$` in the formula is usually a bad sign. you might consider merging the extra co-variate data into the data.frame. Here I also show an alternative way of building the formula using `bquote()`

```
lapply(names(other), function(x) {
    glm.nb(bquote(Days ~ Sex/(Age + Eth*Lrn) + .(as.name(x))), 
        data = cbind(quine, other))
})
```